# Flushing AST CDT

Tags: eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree, flush

I made some changes in AST via ASTRewrite and applied the changes via Change.perform, the C file has been update correctly with the new changes (insert new node), but in the debug mode AST object doesn't feel those changes

```
    ast.getRawSignature(); // C file code as text
    ASTRewrite rewriter = ASTRewrite.create(ast);
    addNewNode(node, ast, rewriter); //Inserting some node
    Change c = rewriter.rewriteAST();
            try {
                c.perform(new NullProgressMonitor());
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    /**WHAT I WANT TO FLUSH THE AST HERE TO FEEL THE CHANGES**/
    ast.getRawSignature(); //it still the same C old code and the C file already updated
```

I need to flush the AST to feel those change in the AST object itself, How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

After an AST is initially constructed, it is no longer mutable ([`IASTTranslationUnit.freeze()`](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2Fast%2FIASTTranslationUnit.html) is called on it, and any further attempts to call setters on nodes in that AST will fail).

This means that `Change.perform()` cannot perform the changes on the AST, only on the file. To get an AST that reflects the changes, you need to build a new one.

Comment: That's what I am doing in the code provided, the changes appear in the file it self, but not the ast object

Comment: @MostafaHassan: My bad, I overlooked that. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Building new AST that what I have done already before submit this question,just want to make sure that I am thinking in the right direction. Thanks @HighCommander4